# Embedding a UITableView inside another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to create a UITableView view (I guess a subview) inside another controller's view. Essentially here is the (simplified) structure I want for the Settings page I am designing:

- SettingsViewController.h - contains standard property and method definitions.
- SettingsViewController.m - controls the loading and saving of settings.
- SettingsViewController.xib - the parent view for everything going on inside

  - 3x UISegmentedControls - each one will control a different setting. They will take up about half of the screen - the top half.
  - 1x UITableView -  covers the rest of the screen and is scrollable. Scrolling shouldn't make the other controls disappear.

I tried adding a UITableView object to my .XIB file, then creating outlets for it inside the SettingsViewController.h file, but that didn't quite work. The table showed, but only in its default format - none of the DataSource methods worked.

I got rid of the code (temporarily), but if you need specifics, I should be able to reproduce it quickly and offer you some. Plus, I might do it right this time...

P.S. Using UITableView is not mandatory. If there is another handy way of displaying and editing a list of items (NSStrings really), I'd be fine with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your tableView is empty and the dataSource methods are correctly implemented you probably just forgot to connect your tableView to the dataSource/delegate.

control-drag from the tableView to the viewController and set dataSource and delegate.

Comment: You also need to implement the delegate and datasource methods in your controller. Add the protocol to SettingsViewController.h

Comment: Both dataSource and delegate should by my SettingsViewController, yes? Assuming that's where I am will be doing all of the logic for the table.